# Universal control of ESP32

Tags: alexa, esp32, google-home, gpio, matter

I need a help that, if exists a code, library, software which can control my ESP32 GPIO pins. ie, 1 code, connect to google home, alexa, home kit, home assistant, samsung smartthings, etc....(MATTER)

Comment: Since you specifically mentioned Matter, did you try searching the web for "ESP32 Matter"?

Comment: matter device is too complex and confusing to build, cant test it, give can't add unrecognized device..., Any other options?

Comment: You're the one who mentioned Matter in your question. There are thousands of tutorials online about how to control an ESP32 remotely and interface it with voice assistants. Searching the web would be a good start.